# Does xdebug 2.7.1 support php 7.0 ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

I have installed xdebug using this commend

```
sudo apt install PHP-xdebug
```

[image]

Does xdebug 2.7.1 support php 7.0?

If not, how can I downgrade
 xdebug in ubuntu 18

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check the compatibility matrix on the xdebug website?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it support PHP 7.0

*Release notes Version 2.7.1 (stable):*

> **PHP** Version: PHP **7.0.0** or newer
>
> PEAR Package: PEAR 1.9.1 or newer

Check the official doc [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/xdebug/2.7.1)

In case you want to downgrade the version . unintall it and then intall the your prefered one .